# In Modern Communication Site, Home Page Layout Fails to Apply When Creating Pages from Template with Home Layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, page-layout, homepage

I've encountered an issue with creating a custom page template in a Modern Communication Site using PowerShell. Although I've successfully applied the Home Page Layout to the template, when a page is created using it, the layout defaults to the Article Page Layout instead of the intended Home Layout.

Here's the sample PowerShell code snippet I used to create the page template:

```
Add-PnPPage -Name "NewPageTemplate" -PromoteAs Template -LayoutType Home
```

While I've found temporary solutions such as manually changing the layout with PowerShell or using browser extensions like SP Editor, these options don't align with our goal of providing a seamless experience for our content editors.

Any assistance in resolving this challenge would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I have seen this behavior previously. I think SharePoint does not support creating/saving "page template" without page title (at least from UI). So, we are using this workaround for creating pages similar to home page (without page header & title): [SharePoint Online: Create a blank page without header & title](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/26/sharepoint-online-create-a-blank-page-without-header-and-title/). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Thanks for your help and sharing this. We already tried this workaround but we there are some problems with this approach. 

Firstly, to rename the page, higher permissions are required compared to what a user need to create and update the page. 

Additionally, while copying the Home Page, users won't all the pre-configured layout that we want to provide as part of the template. 

Therefore, I am still looking for some concrete solution (if any) or any official documentation where it's mentioned that this the default behaviour of SharePoint.

Comment: Yes, user will need contribute permissions to rename the page name (delete permissions are required). However, you can have the pre-configured layout/web parts with the method mentioned above.